# Indy EIdHTTPProtocolException HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Пытаюсь воспользоваться API ресурса. Для запроса с авторизацией руководствуюсь данной инструкцией https://bitfinex.readme.io/v1/docs/rest-auth В качестве эксперимента скомпилировал приведенный там пример на Go, проверил свои ключи на работоспособность и посмотрел в снифере передающийся запрос, который выглядит так:

```
POST https://api.bitfinex.com/v1//account_infos HTTP/1.1
Host: api.bitfinex.com
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
X-Bfx-Apikey: FVnFV0rjeLplpHLBWZbdD8uVYOyLWObLaLLrQwDhy3y
X-Bfx-Payload: eyJub25jZSI6IjEwMDAwMDAxIiwicmVxdWVzdCI6Ii92MS9hY2NvdW50X2luZm9zIn0=
X-Bfx-Signature: d73a4e6aba908a818bf1e0fce4d98c3fe1e48e58355a3ec51313631fe257a267a52d0cea19da5922d6e1abafae84f5ab
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Ключи в примере изменены по соображениям безопасности, но даже так сервер выдает ответ (HTTP/1.1 200 OK) в виде JSON-документа:

```
{"message":"Could not find a key matching the given X-BFX-APIKEY."}
```

Далее в Delphi при помощи Indy пытаюсь сымитировать тот же запрос, создаю клиент:

```
  PostList := TStringStream.Create;
  IdHttp1 := TIdHttp.Create();
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
  IdHttp1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
  Idhttp1.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol,hoForceEncodeParams];
  Idhttp1.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  Idhttp1.Request.UserAgent := 'Go-http-client/1.1';
  Idhttp1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  Idhttp1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
  Idhttp1.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, identity;q=0';

{для упрощения примера упускаю кусок формирования ключей, сразу подставляю готовые значения}

  Idhttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Bfx-Apikey'] := 'FVnFV0rjeLplpHLBWZbdD8uVYOyLWObLaLLrQwDhy3y';
  Idhttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Bfx-Payload'] := 'eyJub25jZSI6IjEwMDAwMDAxIiwicmVxdWVzdCI6Ii92MS9hY2NvdW50X2luZm9zIn0=';
  Idhttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['X-Bfx-Signature'] := 'd73a4e6aba908a818bf1e0fce4d98c3fe1e48e58355a3ec51313631fe257a267a52d0cea19da5922d6e1abafae84f5ab';
  Response := Idhttp1.Post('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1//account_infos', PostList);
```

Запрос через снифер моего клиента выглядит немного иначе, чем в примере на Go, но не думаю что эти критично:

```
POST https://api.bitfinex.com/v1//account_infos HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
X-Bfx-Apikey: FVnFV0rjeLplpHLBWZbdD8uVYOyLWObLaLLrQwDhy3y
X-Bfx-Payload: eyJub25jZSI6IjEwMDAwMDAxIiwicmVxdWVzdCI6Ii92MS9hY2NvdW50X2luZm9zIn0=
X-Bfx-Signature: d73a4e6aba908a818bf1e0fce4d98c3fe1e48e58355a3ec51313631fe257a267a52d0cea19da5922d6e1abafae84f5ab
Host: api.bitfinex.com
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, identity;q=0
User-Agent: Go-http-client/1.1
```

Но тут, всегда получаю EIdHTTPProtocolException HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request, если отправлять правильные ключи. В случае с неверными ключами получаем EIdHTTPProtocolException HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized.
Версия Indy - 10.6.0.5040. Библиотеки OpenSSL лежат в системе и используются другими приложениями без сбоев. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) У вас в `url` два слеша подряд идут: `v1//account_infos` - удалите один:

```
Response := Idhttp1.Post('https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/account_infos', PostList);
```

2) Чтобы `Indy` мог распаковывать `gzip` контент, ему нужно помочь:

```
uses  
  IdCompressorZLib

...

IdHttp1.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(IdHttp1);
```

3) Чтобы не получать исключения при плохих ответах сервера (3xx-4xxx), в опциях Indy надо передать `hoNoProtocolErrorException`, а также `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` - чтобы получить тело ответа, если оно есть.

```
Idhttp1.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol,hoForceEncodeParams,hoNoProtocolErrorException,hoWantProtocolErrorContent];
```

---

С приведенными изменениями, у меня в итоге в `Response` приходит сообщение от сервера:

```
{"message":"Could not find a key matching the given X-BFX-APIKEY."}
```

При этом, код ответа сервера (если посмотреть в `Idhttp1.ResponseCode`) по прежнему остаётся **401**.

Если вы теперь подставите валидные значения ключей, сервер вам по прежнему должен вернуть код **400**, но теперь вы сможете прочитать ещё и тело ответа и возможно там вам напишут, в чём ваша ошибка и почему ваш запрос "плохой".

Comment: они там в обоих случаях такие. вряд ли это причина разных ответов

Comment: Да, я тоже на это обращал внимание. В рабочем примере на Go почему-то с двумя слешами отправляет. Пробовал удалять лишний слеш, но причина действительно не в нем.

Comment: @HeathRow тогда остаётся поле `Accept-Encoding` - единственное отличие от Go, если вы, конечно, снифером всё правильно посмотрели.

Comment: @HeathRow Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @zed Благодарю за участие. Но увы ничего не помогло. Добавил компрессор. Опции `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` у меня нет, вероятно она появилась в более новых версиях, А при добавлении 'hoNoProtocolErrorException' Exception пропадает, но и Response остается пустым. От `identity` в разделе `Accept-Encoding`, как я не пытался избавится, но так и не смог. В Indy оно похоже неубиваемо, но как я понял, вычитав на одним из форумов `identity;q=0` ее отключает. Так же не думаю, что вся беда в этом.

Comment: @Heathrow Обновите Indy или Delphi.

Comment: @zed После установки Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update2 и добавив недостающие в прошлой версии опции, которые Вы мне посоветовали, все заработало. Теперь показывает ответы сервера с любом кодом от сервера. Спасибо!