# как распаковать gzip с ID 0x1F 0x3F вместо 0x1F 0x8B, Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, gzip, indy, delphi-xe7

Помогите пожалуйста распаковать gzip файл.

получаю gzip

```
idHttp.Request.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
idHttp.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
idHttp.Request.Host := 'home.mobile.de';
idHttp.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, br';
idHttp.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36';
idHttp.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
idHttp.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
idHttp.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';

try
    res := idHttp.get('https://home.mobile.de/home/ses.html?customerId=2259797&segment=Car&pageNumber=1&sortBy=price&fetchMore=true&json=true');
```

не могу распаковать файл, вроде бы gzip, но ID2 отличается.
gzip должен иметь :

**$1F $8B**, мои все файлы имеют **$1F $3F**

и при распаковки получаю ошибку Data Error. Пробую через ZLib :

```
    procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    FileStream: TFileStream;
    DecompressionStream: TDecompressionStream;
    Strings: TStringList;
begin
    FileStream := TFileStream.Create(MyDir + '\testid.gz', fmOpenRead);
    DecompressionStream := TDecompressionStream.Create(FileStream, 16 + 15);
    Strings := TStringList.Create;
    Strings.LoadFromStream(DecompressionStream);
    ShowMessage(Strings[0]);
end;
```

Описания gz с ID **0x1F 0x3F** не нашёл, как с ним работать ?

7zip и WinRar их не берут.

Comment: Из `AcceptEncoding` уберите строчку `br` (brotli), раз вы ожидаете именно gzip.

Comment: Пробывал, ничего не происходит, все точно также как и с br (brotli). Только если убрать gzip получаем чистый текст без сжатия. Даже если оставить только gzip, то получаем всё теже 0x1F 0x3F

Comment: Попробуйте подключить распаковщика gzip в Indy, как сказано тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670901/177722

Answer (score 0):

[Наткнулся](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27612450/9423788) на решение Вашего вопроса.

```
var
    HTTP: TIdHTTP;
    JSON: string;
begin
   HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
    HTTP.Compressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create(HTTP);
    HTTP.Request.CharSet := 'UTF-8';
    HTTP.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
    HTTP.Request.Host := 'home.mobile.de';
    HTTP.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate, br';
    HTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36';
    HTTP.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7';
    HTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
    HTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
    JSON := HTTP.Get('https://home.mobile.de/home/ses.html?customerId=2259797&segment=Car&pageNumber=1&sortBy=price&fetchMore=true&json=true');
    finally
    Http.Free;
    end;
    ShowMessage(JSON);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

> не могу распаковать файл, вроде бы gzip, но ID2 отличается. gzip должен иметь

Возможно там не gzip, а brotli
поэтому br из IdHTTP2.Request.AcceptEncoding нужно исключить,
т.е. вот так:

```
IdHTTP2.Request.AcceptEncoding := 'gzip, deflate';
```

Answer (score -1):

скачал файл по вашей ссылке: https://home.mobile.de/home/ses.html?customerId=2259797&segment=Car&pageNumber=1&sortBy=price&fetchMore=true&json=true

это обычный json (текстовый файл)

```
{"searchMetadata":{"resultsFound":20,"totalResults":210...
```

Comment: Это если через браузер заходить, браузер автоматически распаковывает. Как вариант можно ещё отключить gzip в AcceptEncoding, но хотелось бы правильного решения.

Comment: Мой браузер ничего не распаковывает а сразу получает json данные. Проверил через https://apitester.com/ - приходит json. В приходящем заголовке "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Сохраните файл и попробуйте открыть хотя-бы блокнотом.

Comment: Если делаешь запрос через indy то получаешь gzip. То что apitester.com показывает text я видел, тоже самое как и браузер. Более того если в indy убрать gzip то получаешь чистый текст, но это не цель задачи.

Comment: Еще раз попробовал сделать через apitester: пришел gzip в котором файл без расширения с таким содержимым:

Zugriff verweigert / Access denied
Leider koennen wir Ihnen an dieser Stelle keinen Zugriff auf unsere Daten gewaehren. 
Sollten Sie weiterhin Interesse an einem Bezug unserer Daten haben, wenden sie sich bitte an:

Unfortunately, automated access to this page was denied. 
If you are interested in accessing our data, please contact:
 
Frederick Altrock 

Phone:
+49 (0) 30 8109-7573

Mail:
datenpartner@team.mobile.de

mobile.de GmbH
...

Comment: Проблема в apitester.com

Comment: Выложите файл в любой файлообменник, посмотрим.